# Problemas al ejecutar .jar en otras PC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, java-8, crud

He hecho un sistema de inventario con Login, con java y sql server 18.

El programa me corre bien en el IDE de NetBeans, al igual que si saco el jar, corre bien en mi computadora, el problema es cuando yo quiero ejecutarlo en otra computadora, no me deja, meto el usuario y se queda trabado y se sale por si mismo, les dejo mi conexión y mi código de inicio sesión. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver el problema?
Ya incluso puse la ip de la base de datos y quite el LocalHost

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.SQLException;

   public class Conexion {
    public static Connection 
   getConexion(){
        
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.2:1433;" 
                + "database=Inventario;"
                + "user=Admin;"
                + "password=******;";
        
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

Porfavor, ya he tratado de hacer absolutamente todo, pero no funciona en pc de otras personas, ni con jar, ni con exe, pero en la mia si, me funciona con ambas

Comment: En la otra computadora, ¿instalaste el servidor?  Cuando lo corres de manera local tienes que instalar el servidor.

Comment: No, en la otra computadora no le instale el sql Server, ¿Eso es esencial, no?

Comment: De manera local tengo el servidor que esl Sql Server Management

Comment: Con el programa "SQL server Configuration Manager" tienes que habilitar el protocolo TCP/IP para que entre maquinas se puedan comunicar con la maquina donde tienes el servicio SQL Server

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593563/error-al-conectar-sql-server-v%c3%ada-tcp-ip-connect-timed-out)

Comment: Ya le he configurado eso, pero sigue igual, todas deben de estar conectadas a la misma red, no?

Comment: Sip, muchas gracias, me resolvió muchas dudas, perl mi conexión esta bien

Comment: Sólo es necesario instalar cuando lo utilizas de forma local, de lo contrario con la ip sería suficiente., por otro lado, estás utilizando el puerto 1433, ¿es esto correcto?

Comment: Sip, es esto correcto

Comment: @AnaChristaVegs que te sale cuando lo corres como java -jar C:/miaplicacion.jar?