# ¿Como conectar mi Sql Server a mi instancia de aws RDS?

Tags: sql-server, aws

Estoy tratando de conectar mi instancia creada en AWS, pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seguido todos los pasos de la documentación [UserGuide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html) y nada.

-Mi estado esta disponible:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
-Esta activo mi VPC y tengo accesibilidad habilitada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Coloco mi server name como me lo da aws:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al último le coloco el puerto con una coma antes como lo muestran en el ejemplo `database-2.cg034itsfake.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433`, junto con el usuario y la contraseña con la que se configuro.

Alguien sabe si me falta un paso? o si estoy realizando mal mis pasos ? Les agradeceria mucho cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593592/21

Comment: Muchas gracias, la voy a leer! No me habia salido esa respuesta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593563/error-al-conectar-sql-server-v%c3%ada-tcp-ip-connect-timed-out)