# Cannot Connecto TO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2019

hace días estaba trabajando en un servidor (SQL SERVER). Desde ayer me percaté que ya no puedo conectar :(, he probado muchos metodos...

el error es:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to NOMBRE DB.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=47; handshake=29990;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver--2-database-engine-error

---

Tiempo de espera de la operación de espera agotado

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

print de pantalla:
[image: iprint de pantalla del error]

Ruego su ayuda...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593563/error-al-conectar-sql-server-v%c3%ada-tcp-ip-connect-timed-out)

Comment: también agrega el método de autentificación

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversas causas para esto, pero todas tienen que ver con la configuración y conectividad de la red. Hay varias cosas que puedes validar para solucionar esto.

1. Que el servicio de SQL Server esté iniciado.
2. Que el servicio de SQL Server Browser esté iniciado.
3. Que los protocolos de TCP/IP estén habilitados para IPV4 e IPV6
4. Que el nombre del servidor o su dirección IP (con puerto en caso de no ser el predeterminado) esté escrito correctamente.
5. Que haya conectividad de red entre el cliente y el servidor.
6. Que no estés siendo bloqueado por el firewall
7. Que el servidor permita conexiones remotas.