# ¿Como puedo resolver el error "error de conexion BDSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, .net

Estaba realizando una aplicacion en Visual Studio usando .NET, C# y SQL server, llevo rato intentando realizar la conexión a la base de datos pero me salta el siguiente error:

```
Error de conexion BDsystem.Data.SqlClient-SqlException (0x80131904): Eror relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una
conexión con el servidor SOL Server, No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL
Sener está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - El equipo remoto rechazó la conexión de red —>
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (080004005): El equipo remoto rechazó la conexión de red

en System.Data SalClient SalintemalConnectionTds..ctor[DbConnectionPoolidentity identity, SalConnectionstring connectionOptions, SalCredential
credential, Object providerinfo, String newPassuord, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserinstance, SqlConnectionstring:
userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling,
SalauthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

en System-Data SalClient.SalConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolkey poolkey, Object
poolGroupProviderinfo, DbConnectionPoo! pool, DbConnection oumingConnectian, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

en System.Data ProviderBase DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject,
DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolkey poolkey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

en System.Data ProviderBase DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObjed, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionintemal
oldConnection)

en System.Data ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequestíDbConnection owningObjed, DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
DbConnectionintemal oldConnection)

en System.Data ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TyGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionintemalá: connection)

en System.Data ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoo.TIyGetConnection(DbConnection owningObjed, TaskCompletionSource + ret, DbConnectionOptions
useroptions, DbConnectionintemalét connection)

en System.Data ProviderBaseDbConnectionFactory.TIyGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry,
DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionintemal oldConnection, DbConnectionintemalá: connection)

en System.Data ProviderBase.DbConnectonintemal.TIyOpenConnectionintemal[DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
connectionFactony, TaskCompletionsource 1 ret, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

en System.Data ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TyOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFacton,
TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions useroptions)

en System.Data SaiClient SalConnection TryOpeninner(faskCompletionSource1 retny)

en System.Data SaiClient.salConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource 1 retry)

en System.Data SalClient SalConnection.Open)

en LoginApp.Clases.Cconexion.realizarConexion( en CAUsere Desgen sourceVrepos LoginAppVLoginAppVClases Cconexion.estínea 32
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:1225,State:0 Class:20
```

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

-en mi clase para establecer la conexión:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoginApp.Clases //conexion con la bd
{
    internal class Cconexion
    {
        SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection();

        static string servidor = "localhost";
        static string bd = "users";
        static string usuario = "admin";
        static string password = "admin";
        static string puerto = "1433"; 

        //pasamos todos los parametros para la conexion
        static string cconexion = "Data Source="+servidor+","+puerto+";"+"user id="+usuario+";"+"password="+password+";"+"Initial Catalog="+bd+";"+"Persist Security Info=true";
        

        //funcion para realizar conexion y verificarla
        public SqlConnection realizarConexion() 
        { 

            try
            {
                conex.ConnectionString = cconexion;
                conex.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Conexion correcta con la BD");
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de conexion BD" + e.ToString()); 
            }
            

            return conex;

        }
    }
}
```

-En la interfaz (cabe aclarar que el boton "Login_Click" lo estoy usando para realizar pruebas de conexion con la bd):

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoginApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clases.Cconexion objetoConexion = new Clases.Cconexion();
            objetoConexion.realizarConexion();

        }
    }
}
```

-SQL server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe realizar cambios en el firewall de windows permitiendo el tráfico, también probe a cambiar las credenciales de conexión y otras cosas, al final todo fallo

Comment: El nombre de la instancia de SQLServer es `\login`? Si es así, tienes que incluirlo en la cadena de conexión.

Comment: ese seria el nombre del servidor, si lo agrego en el codigo, mas exactamente en esta linea : `static string servidor = "localhost";`, quedaria algo asi: `static string servidor = "localhost\login";`, el codigo tira un error de compilacion diciendo "Secuencia de escape no reconocida"

Comment: la pleca invertida inica una secuencia de escape, para que sea reconocida como un caracter válido, tiene que ser doble \\

Comment: algo asi: `static string servidor = "localhost\\login"; `?

Comment: lo acabo de probar y sigue saltando el mismo error, sin ningun cambio

Comment: Puedes poner un `Console.WriteLine(cconexion)` **antes de abrir la conexión** para revisar que el formato esté correcto?

Comment: agregue este codigo: `try
            {
                conex.ConnectionString = cconexion;
                Console.WriteLine("salida: ", cconexion);
                conex.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Conexion correcta con la BD");
            }`

coloque el mensaje de salida para poder identificar el resultado, el resultado es: `Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll
El subproceso 0x38f0 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
`

Comment: Por favor agrega el mensaje de error como texto y no como imagen

Comment: listo, lo agregue como texto en la publicacion principal, despues de la imagen

Comment: La idea era que mostraras el texto de la cadena de conexión. Puedes poner un punto de interrupción sobre la sentencia `.Open()` para ver qué es lo que trae tu variable `cconexion`?

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, despues de un rato experimentando logre conectar con la bd cambie la linea `static string cconexion = "Data Source="+servidor+","+puerto+";"+"user id="+usuario+";"+"password="+password+";"+"Initial Catalog="+bd+";"+"Persist Security Info=true";` por esta otra `static string cconexion = "Data Source=(localdb)\\login; Initial Catalog=users; Integrated Security=True"`

Al final si se realizo la conexion, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593563/error-al-conectar-sql-server-v%c3%ada-tcp-ip-connect-timed-out)

Comment: En la parte inferior existe un lugar para colocar la respuesta, luego procede a marcarla como aceptada, así ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.